# select ng-model sometimes not updating on change event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-model

I am using the Angular `chosen-select`, and I customized it to enable dynamic loading, ie. loading data from server.

When I deselect a value, it removes it from selected items, but it does not update the `ng-model`. But this works fine in IE, but I can see the problem in chrome and Mozilla. I am guessing that it would be something to do with the change event.

Comment: you should show some code

Comment: Demo code pls .. without any code it's like shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```